# Bash Script with Prompts from Xargs?

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a script I am trying to run:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter desired kbps example 1000 for 1000kbps: "
read desired
echo "Please enter minimum kbps: "
read minrate
echo "Please enter maximum kbps: "
read maxrate

for i; do
filename=$(basename "$i")
extension="${filename##*.}"
filename="${filename%.*}"
size=k
    d=$(dirname "$i")
#    b=$(basename "$i")
ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v hevc_nvenc -preset medium -crf 28 -b:v $desired$size -minrate $minrate$size -maxrate $maxrate$size -bufsize 25M -c:a copy "$d/X265_$filename.mp4"
mv "$i" "$d/zzz_$filename.$extension"
done
```

Using this find command with xargs:

```
find ./ -type f -regex ".*\.\(mkv\|mp4\|wmv\|flv\|webm\|mov\|avi\)" -print0 | xargs -0 /root/batch.sh
```

I want it to prompt me once to ask for the bitrate variables, but it doesn't pause for info when utilizing the find command, but it does if I run the script directly.

Is there a way to combine the find command into the other script to make it a simple command that then prompts me for info? If not, what can I do to get it to prompt me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the shell script inherits its standard input from `xargs`, and its input is the pipe from `find`. So the script is trying to read from that pipe.

If you can modify the script, change it to read the inputs from `/dev/tty` instead of standard input. Put this at the beginning of the script:

```
exec </dev/tty
```

Comment: out of curiosity, would that work in script called from cron? Good luck to all!

Comment: No, it wouldn't, this is for interactive prompting.

Comment: The rest of the script should work if you wanted to establish a "watch" folder and then instead of just renaming the files move them out / delete the old ones and place the new in another folder.

Comment: @Alan A better solution might be to change the script so it takes the parameters as option arguments instead of prompting for them. Or it could do both: if the parameter isn't supplied as an option, prompt for it.

Answer (score 3):

You can completely omit the `xargs` part using the `-exec ... +` option
to the `find` command.

Here I've a script that is similar to yours

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh
read a
for i ; do echo -n $i.$a' ' ; done
echo
$
```

a directory with a few files (NB the file names have embedded spaces)

```
$ ls -1 one
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 1
$
```

and eventually an example of using `find` with the `-exec ... +`
option

```
$ find  one -type f -exec sh test.sh '{}' '+'
asdef
one/2 1.asdef one/3 1.asdef one/1 1.asdef one/4 1.asdef 
$
```

---

PS I've edited my answer to reflect OP's concern about filenames with spaces etc... fortunately `find` treats the problem on its own, w/o any problem.